# Given an object, possible to get its class name and convert it to a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Suppose I have the object `*x` of class `Illustration`. Using `x`, I'd like to extract its class name into a string so I have `@"Illustration"`. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use NSStringFromClass.

```
NSString* className = NSStringFromClass([x class]);

NSString* className = [[x class] description];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSStringFromClass([x class])

Comment: No need to post a duplicate answer.